# JavaFX Label doesn't center if not wrapped

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I've encountered a very strange set of circumstances with text wrapping and centered alignment in a JavaFX label. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong or ill-advised, but I cannot seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Basically, I'm attempting to put a title over a tile pane, and have that title be centered. Also, when the window is resized, I'd like the title to wrap. The strangeness comes in when the title is not wrapped (e.g.: one line), it isn't centered any more. As soon as it wraps, it centers again. Here's some sample code that produces the effect:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils;
public class Foo extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        TilePane panel = new TilePane();
        panel.setTileAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            panel.getChildren().add(new Label(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10)));
        }

        Label title = new Label("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit");
        title.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 16; -fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-wrap-text:true; -fx-text-alignment: center -fx-border-color:black;");
        title.minWidthProperty().bind(Bindings.add(-30, primaryStage.widthProperty()));
        title.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

        VBox box = new VBox(title, panel);
        box.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(box, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing. In the first one, the bold line on top is centered and wrapped. In the second one, the bold line on top is not wrapped, and is left-aligned.

[image: wrapped and centered]
[image: not wrapped and not centered]

Comment: Try setting the text alignment, see : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setTextAlignment-javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment-

Comment: Does that work differently than the CSS text alignment that I set already? (-fx-text-alignment: center)

Comment: I dont know, but maybe :)

Comment: Gave it a shot, and it didn't change it. I've updated the code with the changes. I also added a border and made sure the label is wide enough to center.

Comment: Why do you call this "strange"? It is exactly the [specified behavior](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#textAlignmentProperty).

Comment: Since you want a more maintainable and solid way of making your application, I would suggest you looked at FXML and possible scene builder. But, even with these tools, you need to figure out if you wanna wrap the label or hard code it in some way :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#textAlignmentProperty), the text alignment controls the alignment of multi-line text. This is exactly the specified behavior.

If you imagine a rectangle that bounds all the text, when the text has multiple lines a decision has to be made as to how these individual lines are laid out within that rectangle. This is controlled by the `textAlignment` property. The default is to align each line to the left of that box: you can also center, right-align, or justify (expand each line to fill the box). Another way to think of this is that the `textAlignment` only controls the position of each line of text *relative to the other lines of text*.

On the other hand, the `alignment` property defines how the content of the label (text and graphic) is aligned within the label itself, if there is more space in the label than the text occupies. So to center the label in your `VBox` you first need to ensure the label fills the complete width of the `VBox`, and then you need to set the `alignment` property to `CENTER`. You do the former by setting the `maxWidth` of the label so that it grows indefinitely, and setting the `fillWidth()` property of the `VBox` to `true`.

Using Java this looks like

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
{
    TilePane panel = new TilePane();
    panel.setTileAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        panel.getChildren().add(new Label(randomAlphabetic(10)));
    }

    Label title = new Label("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit");
    title.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 16; -fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-wrap-text:true; -fx-border-color:black;");

        title.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        title.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        title.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);


    title.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

    VBox box = new VBox(title, panel);
    box.setFillWidth(true); 

    box.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(box, 400, 400));
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

and you can set these properties in CSS if you prefer:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
{
    TilePane panel = new TilePane();
    panel.setTileAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        panel.getChildren().add(new Label(randomAlphabetic(10)));
    }

    Label title = new Label("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit");
    title.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 16; -fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-wrap-text:true; -fx-border-color:black;"
            + "-fx-text-alignment: center; -fx-alignment: center; -fx-max-width:Infinity; -fx-padding: 5;");


    VBox box = new VBox(title, panel);
    box.setFillWidth(true); // or box.setStyle("-fx-fill-width: true ;")

    box.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(box, 400, 400));
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Comment: James - Thank you for the detailed explanation. It seems that, yet again, reading the documentation produces the answer, sorry for the waste of time on that front. While the documentation explains it clearly, I don't feel that this is intuitive from an end user standpoint. In any case, I put your changes into my application, and it worked like a charm. Thanks again, and marking this as the correct answer! Happy New Year!

Answer (score -1):

Allright i try a some different tacticts and I figured it out with regular css. 
You can use the "-fx-alignment: center;" to do it. See [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#label) for more information about which kind of css to use. Also the width of the label is important, else the width will just be the length of the text and there would be nothing to really center.

Making the changes, your code will look like this

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
{
    TilePane panel = new TilePane();
    panel.setTileAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        panel.getChildren().add(new Label(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10)));
    }

    Label title = new Label("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit");
    title.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 16; -fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-wrap-text:true; -fx-alignment: center; -fx-border-color:black;");
    title.setMinWidth(400); //This is important, else the width will just be the text's length

    VBox box = new VBox(title, panel);
    box.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(box, 400, 400));
    primaryStage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: Won't this break if the scene changes so it is no longer 400 pixels wide?

Comment: Yes it will. Therefore you usally wrap the content in multiple panes to give you the desired behavior to fit no matter the size of the application. One easy way to do this is to wrap the Label in an AnchorPane and make the Label have anchor pane constraints to the left and the right side in this instance.

Comment: Why not just set the appropriate properties? Why all the hacks?

Comment: Im not sure i follow you?

Comment: Setting a hard-coded min width is a hack, and doesn't work if the user resizes the window. Arbitrarily wrapping the label in an `AnchorPane` to achieve what can be achieved simply by setting properties on the existing components you have is a hack that makes your code harder to maintain and understand.

Comment: Look, there are two ways to achieve centering a label. One way is by setting the -fx-alignment to center and setting the width of the label to a specific amount. Then if you want to adding a listener for when the application changes width's so would the label. On the other hand, a more maintainable and preffered approach, is to wrap the label in some panes to achieve the desired centering. This is the approach I would choose, but your question was regarding how to avoid using the wrappings and if it was possible?

Comment: I'm saying this is a poor solution (so is using changing the width in a listener, and so is introducing an unnecessary `AnchorPane`). Just use the provided properties in `Label` and `VBox` so that it behaves in the desired way. (In case it's not clear: I'm not asking you anything; I am explaining why this solution is low-quality.)

Comment: For example, this is really about how this looks (style), not about layout; so a reasonable solution should be entirely attainable solely by CSS.

Comment: My bad, mixed the author and you with each other. But yes I agree doing the hacks are bad, but in this case where you use the VBox, it is still wrapping the label. I just kinda took that for granted, nice solution :)